# How to close all notepad instances in a single close operation

Tags: windows, notepad

I use notepad and often open multiple instances of it. Is there a way to close all instances of it in a single click ?

Closing them one at a is a real pain.

( I do not like to use notepad++ )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a shortcut with command

```
taskkill.exe /im notepad.exe
```

Comment: /F switch can be added to avoid the save prompt and just kill all processes.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to prevent the prompting:

```
taskkill.exe /F /im notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the "Group similar task bar buttons" option (**Start > Properties > Taskbar**) checked, then you should be able to right click on the Notepad group in the taskbar and close all instances of the application.

Comment: In Windows XP you can Ctrl-click to select multiple items on the taskbar as well.

Answer (score -1):

Settings -> Preferences -> MISC. 
There find the option called "Remember current session for next launch" and uncheck it.

Comment: Either this answer is not clear or it isn't intented for **this** question.