# Close all copies of a particular application using the Windows GUI

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, gui

Is there a way to use the Windows GUI (not the command line) to close all copies of a particular running application, when the Taskbar is set to "Never combine"?

The fewer clicks and/or keystrokes, the better.  (For example, one solution would be to individually close each application window, but a quicker way to do this is what I'm after.)

I'm running Windows 8.1, but I would be interested in answers applicable to any recent version of Windows.

Comment: Doesn't the Task Manager do what you want?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't believe so. For example, if I have 5 instances of notepad.exe running, and I want to close them all, if I use Task Manager to kill one of those applications and/or processes, the other 4 remain open.  I'd like to have a way to close all 5 at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close all notepad instances in a single close operation](http://superuser.com/questions/192384/how-to-close-all-notepad-instances-in-a-single-close-operation)

Comment: Before you say "Answers on that duplicate talk about the command-line when I want GUI": a) it's the same question (even if you don't like the answers), and b) the accepted answer is suggesting creating a shortcut to run a command, therefor making the command into a clickable GUI item (a shortcut).  :)

Comment: @techie007 (and users who are voting to close this), this question is different in that it's asking for a method to close instances of *any* arbitrary Windows application (not necessarily known beforehand) -- not always notepad.exe (or some other specific application that can be hard-coded into a shortcut) as in the linked question.

Comment: That being said, maybe making desktop shortcuts to close all instances of *any* application that I ever might want to close all copies of is the best solution, even though that would be a rather ugly hack.  @techie007, feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it if I can't come up with anything better!

Comment: @JonSchneider I see what you're saying regarding arbitrary processes.  I won't add "Make 1000 shortcuts" as an answer myself, since I agree that's not a solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a PowerShell script you can play with.

Currently it makes a form that has a button for each active Process name.

Click the desired button and all processes with that name will be killed.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 

$Processes = Get-Process | Select-Object Name -Unique

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Multi-Process Killer"

function KillProcs($ProcName) {
    Stop-Process -processname $ProcName
    $Form.Close()
}

for($x=0; $x -lt $Processes.Count-1; $x++){
    $Btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $BtnSize = ($x*24)+4;
    $Btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, $BtnSize)
    $Btn.Text = $Processes[$x].Name
    $Btn.Name = "btnKillProc$x"
    $Btn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 24)
    $Btn.TabIndex=$x
    $Btn.Add_Click({ KillProcs($this.Text) })
    $Form.Controls.Add($Btn)
}

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

If I had time, I'd replace all the buttons with a scrollable, selectable listbox and a single "Kill" button, but this should be enough to point you (or someone) in that direction I'm sure. :)

Comment: Nice! I gave this a try and it does work fine on my Windows 8.1 system, albeit with the limitations that you alluded to, like lack of a scrollbar to scroll through the long list of processes.