# Close all notepad.exe windows

Tags: windows, windows-11, notepad

I have a habit of doing the following:

```
win-key notepad
```

whenever I have to jot down a quick note.

In previous versions of windows, I would just kill notepad.exe to close all those windows.

Now, in Windows 11, all those notepad.exe windows stick around.

## `taskkill.exe`

The recommended approach of:

```
taskkill.exe /F /im notepad.exe
```

as mentioned in this post:

[How to close all notepad instances in a single close operation](https://superuser.com/questions/192384/how-to-close-all-notepad-instances-in-a-single-close-operation)

doesn't work; if I run notepad, all the windows come back.

## 'Close all windows`

If I right click on the notepad icon on the taskbar and select 'Close all windows':

[image]

I get a bunch of confirmation dialogs:

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to close all the notepad windows?

Comment: ...doesn't work; if I run notepad, all the windows come back.", what do you mean by the windows come back?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Under Windows 11 after `taskkill.exe`, the first invocation of notepad brings up all the killed windows with their content. The windows need to be closed, which means the user has to click "Don't save" for each. Just another bright idea by Microsoft.

Comment: why don't just use dedicated Notes apps? They can be mapped to a global shortcut key and have much more features. For example OneNote maps to Win+N, [Win+Shift+N](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-onenote-44b8b3f4-c274-4bcc-a089-e80fdcc87950) or Win+Alt+N

Answer (score 1):

To return to the old behavior of notepad, you need to uninstall the
new UWP implementation of notepad. This will make it possible to use
the old notepad from Windows 10, as it's still found in
`C:\Windows\System32`. You will need to ignore the message about
a newer version.

This is discussed in detail in the article
[How to Restore Old Classic Notepad in Windows 11](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-old-classic-notepad-windows/).
Below is a summary of the methods:

**Method 1: Disable the Notepad App execution alias**

- Open *Settings > Apps > Advanced app settings*
- Click "App execution aliases"
- Find "Notepad" in the list and turn off the radio button.

The effect is immediate.

If Microsoft has removed `notepad.exe` from `C:\Windows\System32`,
you might be able to return it by the following two methods.

**Install the classic Notepad program via Optional features**

- Open *Settings > System > Optional features"
- Click "View features"
- Type `notepad`
- Click install
  Select Notepad (system) from the list, and click Next.

**Using the DISM command-line to install Classical Notepad**

- Run and elevated CMD and enter this command :

  ```
  dism /Online /add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.Notepad.System~~~~0.0.1.0
  ```

**Method 2: Restore Classic Notepad via the registry**

Execute this `.reg` file :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Restore Old Classic Notepad on Windows 11
;Created by Ramesh Srinivasan for Winhelponline.com
;Created on May 6, 2022; Revised on May 12, 2022.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe]
"NoOpenWith"=-

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,-102"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"UseFilter"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you Harry!

Comment: Hey Harry! Yup, your answer is very helpful and insightful. I also like the approach provided by @1NN in another answer. It seems straightforward and seems to work well. What do you think about that approach?

Comment: @dharmatech: I don't like to talk against answers by others. My personal approach is not to modify folders created by Windows software, also because they may return, but sometimes it's necessary.

Comment: Harry, I totally understand. Thank you! 

Answer (score 1):

After `taskkill`, delete the subfolders and contents of the following folder:

```
  %localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\
```

The `8wekyb3d8bbwe` part could be different on your system.

This will delete all autosaves and tab states, so afterwards a clean notepad will open.

It should be easy to wrap both commands into a batch file.

Comment: Works great, thank you!